# Varnish caching one vhost but not another?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, varnish

I have a default vhost setup on my Debian box (a demo, I wanted to see how Varnish caching works and whether it could solve a speed problem).

All was well with the default host, lots of cache hits and the occasional miss. Cool.

So I added a vhost through Apache, hooked up WordPress (I know about the cookie problems) and tried loading it's readme.html file. Still quick, but it's stopped hitting/missing the cache altogether, despite having absolutely no dynamic references. Images also aren't cached at all.

Any suggestions for what could be going wrong? I used a2ensite but above that did no additional configuration for the new vhost.

Answer (score 0):

What cookies are in use? Unless you strip them out varnish will consider the content un-cachable. Also, post a copy of your config so people can see exactly what you're running.

**EDIT:** I re-read you question and see you say you've already sorted cookies. Can we still see your config?

Comment: Okay well here goes: [that failed. since when did return submit??]
CONFIG:
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
        # Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
        sub vcl_recv {
                if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                        unset req.http.cookie;
                }
        }

        # Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
        sub vcl_fetch {
                if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                        unset obj.http.set-cookie;
                }
        }

Comment: However, I only added the wordpress bits recently, and now on compiling I get this: 
Message from VCC-compiler:
'obj.http.set-cookie': cannot be unset in method 'vcl_fetch'.
At: ('input' Line 21 Pos 31)
                        unset obj.http.set-cookie;
------------------------------###################-

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed

(Note- Varnish wasn't caching at all with static things like images and the readme file either so the lack of the cookie thing ^ didnt change that. From:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VarnishAndWordpress

Comment: @George - can you just edit your original question, and add the config to the end of your post? Or just use pastebin.com

Comment: Try vcl_rcv instead